# Не нужно ли помочь длиннющему предложению точками с запятой?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, точка-с-запятой

> И как я ни пыталась себя успокоить, всё же зал ресторана поразил меня
>   головокружительной высотой потолка, навстречу зазвучали звуки арфы,
>   которые, казалось, исходили из моего истерзанного сердца, а вокруг
>   меня (той, у которой в пустом кошельке лежала «карточка покупателя» на
>   приобретение унизительного количества мыла, водки и сахара в месяц)
>   ломились столы, уставленные невероятными яствами – высокие вазы в
>   начале зимы переполняли, свисая гигантскими кистями, заморские фрукты,
>   на льду лежала икра и невероятное количество сортов рыбы и гадов
>   морских, что отливали перламутром, мясная нарезка украшала стройными
>   рядами зеркальные серебряные блюда, сыры уютно устроились в стеклянных
>   домиках-шкафчиках, пухлыми боками отражали каждое мое движение котлы,
>   в которых, судя по тонким ароматам, томились гастрономические
>   сюрпризы, белоснежные скатерти, сверкающие приборы, изысканная
>   сервировка и бесшумный сонм невозмутимых официантов...

Друзья! Если заметите другие ошибки, свистните, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В предложенном виде текст читается легко, мгновенно создает понимание ощущений девочки; точки с запятой, двоеточия, по-моему, вызвали бы дискомфорт "спотыкания" об них. Свистнул бы, чтобы убрать и кавычки с "карточки покупателя".

Comment: А, Серпик с Молоточком! «Карточка покупателя»это как бы имя собственное некой картонки.  И второй довод "за": описан 1992-й; не всякий народ помнит о таком документе (в отличие от аттестата, диплома, проездного).

Comment: Ах, ну, если имя собственное, то тогда конечно. И, коль скоро вы употребили "как бы", замечу, что его давно уже пишут с "е" вместо "ы". С уважением к Вам, СерпИ.Молот, а не Серпик с Молоточком)

Answer (score 1):

Я бы поставил двоеточие после яств (идет перечисление) и использовал точки с запятой.

И как я ни пыталась себя успокоить, всё же зал ресторана поразил меня головокружительной высотой потолка, навстречу зазвучали звуки арфы, которые, казалось, исходили из моего истерзанного сердца, а вокруг меня (той, у которой в пустом кошельке лежала «карточка покупателя» на приобретение унизительного количества мыла, водки и сахара в месяц) ломились столы, уставленные невероятными яствами(:) высокие вазы в начале зимы переполняли, свисая гигантскими кистями, заморские фрукты(;) на льду лежала икра и невероятное количество сортов рыбы и гадов морских, что отливали перламутром(;) мясная нарезка украшала стройными рядами зеркальные серебряные блюда(;) сыры уютно устроились в стеклянных домиках-шкафчиках(;) пухлыми боками отражали каждое мое движение котлы, в которых, судя по тонким ароматам, томились гастрономические сюрпризы(.)

Последняя часть (белоснежные скатерти, сверкающие приборы, изысканная сервировка и бесшумный сонм невозмутимых официантов...) к яствам не относится. Надо бы поставить точку перед ней. Полагаю, на месте троеточия есть продолжение фразы, но какое именно - неизвестно, и это затрудняет ответ.

Comment: Нет, многоточием заканчивается абзац. В предложенные знаки сейчас вдумаюсь; спасибо за помощь.

Comment: В последней части недостает сказуемого. Как будто автора прервали на полуслове. Это еще один повод выделить эту часть в отдельное предложение.

Answer (score 1):

**Не очень понятно, какое помещение ресторана описывается:** основной зал, подсобное помещение , кухня или всё сразу. Такое впечатление, что это экскурсия по ресторану:  зал, где формируются готовые заказы, кухня, где в котлах готовятся горячие блюда, банкетный (основной) зале, где обслуживаются посетители (скатерти, приборы, официанты).

**В тексте всё как-то перемешано, а переход к основному залу вообще непонятен**, поэтому я дополнила недостающее (как мне кажется) содержание произвольным образом.

И как я ни пыталась себя успокоить, всё же  зал ресторана поразил меня головокружительной высотой потолка, навстречу зазвучали звуки арфы, а вокруг меня **ломились столы, уставленные невероятными яствами:** высокие вазы в начале зимы переполняли, свисая гигантскими кистями, заморские фрукты, на льду лежала икра и невероятное количество сортов рыбы и гадов морских, что отливали перламутром, мясная нарезка украшала стройными рядами зеркальные серебряные блюда, сыры уютно устроились в стеклянных домиках-шкафчиках;

**на кухне** пухлыми боками отражали каждое мое движение котлы, в которых, судя по тонким ароматам, томились гастрономические сюрпризы,

**а в зале для посетителей** - белоснежные скатерти, сверкающие приборы, изысканная сервировка и бесшумный сонм невозмутимых официантов...

Comment: Да, "котлы" определённо намекают на кухню, - а её нельзя - случайно! - увидеть из главного зала? Спрошу. А дописывать ничего нельзя.

Comment: Но переход к скатертям совершенно непонятен, там, как мне кажется, нет грамматической связи.

Comment: Ну пусть будет "поток сознания"; я понимаю, как 19-летнюю девочку оглушило ВСЁ.

Comment: Автор откликнулся: "В том-то и дело, что всё перечисленное находится в зале, где проходит завтрак. И до сих пор этим отличается *Европейская* от всех остальных отелей".

Comment: Поддерживаю @Sibylla в том, что у последней части (начиная со скатертей) нет грамматической связи  с остальным, я об этом тоже писал. Просится хоть какая-то правка, например: слепили глаза/а дальше/и наконец/и вдобавок белоснежные скатерти, сверкающие приборы, изысканная сервировка и бесшумный сонм невозмутимых официантов...

Comment: И еще. Если оставить тире перед списком "яств", то разве не требуется второе тире в конце этого списка?